# CS50 - pset2 - Vigenere

Tags: vigenere

I am currently struggling with pset2, specifically with vigenere.

Here is my code :

```
# include <cs50.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{

    //Assess the fact that there is only 1 command line argument
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("You should only have 1 command line argument !\n") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    string k = argv[1] ;
    int klength = strlen(k) ;

    for(int i = 0; i < klength; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(k[i]))
        {
            printf("Please make sure the argument is only composed of alphabetical characters\n") ;
            return 1 ;
        }
    }

    //Get the text to be crypted
    string s = GetString() ;
    int slength = strlen(s) ;

    //Deliver the crypted text
    for( int i = 0, j = 0 ; i < slength ; i++)
    {
        int kindex = j % klength ;

        if(isalpha(s[i]))
        {
            if(isupper(s[i]))
            {
                if(isupper(k[kindex]))
                {
                    int crypt = (((s[i] - 'A') + (k[kindex] - 'A') % 26)) + 'A' ;
                    printf("%c", crypt ) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    int crypt = (((s[i] - 'A') + (k[kindex] - 'a')) % 26) + 'A' ;
                    printf("%c", crypt ) ;
                }
            }
            if(islower(s[i]))
            {
                if(isupper(k[kindex]))
                {
                    int crypt = (((s[i] - 'a') + (k[kindex] - 'A')) % 26) + 'a' ;
                    printf("%c", crypt) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    int crypt = (((s[i] - 'a') + (k[kindex] - 'a')) % 26) + 'a' ;
                    printf("%c", crypt ) ;
                }
            }
        j++ ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c" , s[i]) ;
        }
    }

    printf("\n") ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

With check50, here are the errors I receive :

:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "CaQGon" using "BaZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "CakGon\n"
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "CAQGON" using "BAZ" as keyword
   \ expected output, but not "CAkGOh\n"

Here is my sandbox : [sandbox](https://sandbox.cs50.net/checks/74232b6cad064658911b8ce07f60313f)
I don't understand why the two outputs are not the same (cakgon vs cakoh) and why it differs from what is expected. The problem probably resides in the part "//Deliver the crypted test".

I have spent a few hours trying to figure it out without success.

Thanks in advance for any help / tip / piece of advice.

Baptiste

Comment: You didn't describe any problem you are having.

Comment: I have edited the post, trying to describe the problem more carefully. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it.
Parentheses were missing before one of the "%26".